# Android Emulator change phone number unknown to number default

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to get the phone number of the emulator, but when I check the phone number in setting-about phone-status, the phone number shows 'unknown'. Sometimes the pone number shows a number. How can I get the phone number of the android emulator. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your emulator does not have a phone number. If you want to "call" it or "SMS" it here is how:
1. In eclipse open the DDMS perspective. (Upper-right corner, click the little new window button ->DDMS
2. On the left hand side under emulator control you should see a section called "Telephony Actions"
3. There you can enter your own phone number (this will be the incoming number) as well as call or even write an SMS (Check SMS and than compose in the box).
4. Hit send and you should see it come in on your emulator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I find this solution, i just restart the emulator , and my emulator show this phone number, thanks :)

Comment: If this answered you question, checking the check mark next to it will help other people know this is the right answer. I am glad I could help out a fellow developer.